# Curved line at the bottom of the image div

Tags: html, css

[image]

I want to draw this curve using border-radius in CSS.
I have tried different options using border-radius but couldn't get success.

Thank You in advance for any help.

Comment: This would be difficult to replicate flawlessly through CSS. The best solution is usually to use an SVG file instead.

Comment: If you can get away with falling back to a flat bottom for Internet Explorer, you could leverage [CSS Shapes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Shapes)

Comment: Can you post one of your failed code to see what is wrong with it?

Comment: Hi Lucas I have tried border-radius: 0 0 95% 40%/0 0 60% 35% in CSS. But it is not give me the correct output for the right end of the curve.

Comment: Hi  chriskirknielsen how can i use SVG in html?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One SVG solution might be something like:

```html
<svg id="svg" version="1.1" width="400" height="50" style="display: block;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g id="svgg">
    <path id="path0" d="M 0 29.342 C 0 29.342 32.3 33.254 34.5 33.52 C 48.245 35.186 84.982 36.994 105 36.991 C 142.726 36.985 173.069 33.939 229 24.544 C 284.522 15.218 290.649 11.618 391.5 9.71 L 399.081 9.645 L 399.11 0 L 0 0" fill-rule="evenodd" style="fill: rgb(62, 73, 160);"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

You can paste this code right into your HTML document or save it with a .svg extension and use as a regular image. Hope this work.

Comment: Remember that you can open the SVG file in any SVG editor and change it to fit your needs.

Comment: Thanks Lucas its worked. But i got new problem it is not responsive. Do you know any solution?